# Proving estimate of tail of cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, distribution-tails

I tried to prove the following estimation, with no success:

$$\int_z^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt= \frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z}(1-z^{-1}+\mathcal{O}(z^{-2}))$$

Any advice on how to prove this?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Integrate by parts the LHS twice, using $\displaystyle\int uv'=uv-\int u'v$ with $v(t)=\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$ each time. [This will show you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) that the formula in your post should read
$$
\int_z^\infty\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}}z\,\left(1-\frac1{z^2}+O\left(\frac1{z^4}\right)\right).
$$
**Edit:** Here are the two integrations by parts mentioned above.

- First integration by parts: $u(t)=-1/t$, $v(t)=\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$, results in
  $$
  \int_z^\infty\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}}z-\int_z^\infty\frac1{t^2}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt.$$
- Second integration by parts: $u(t)=-1/t^3$, $v(t)=\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$, results in
  $$
  \int_z^\infty\frac1{t^2}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}}{z^3}-3\int_z^\infty\frac1{t^4}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt.$$
- Estimate of the remainder term: $1/t^4\leqslant t/z^5$ on $(z,+\infty)$ hence
  $$
  0\leqslant\int_z^\infty\frac1{t^4}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_z^\infty\frac{t}{z^5}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm e^{-z^2/2}}{z^5}.$$

Comment: I dont get your hint. Two times integrating by parts gives: $\int_z^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt= -ze^{-z^2/2}+\int_{z}^\infty t^2e^{-t^2/2} dt=-ze^{-z^2/2}-\frac{1}{3}z^3e^{-z^2/2}+\int_{z}^\infty\frac{ t^4}{3} e^{-t^2/2} dt$

Comment: Yes, that is because you did not read it: the hint is to consider $v(t)=\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$, not $u(t)=\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}$.

Comment: Ye I just recognized. Thank you very much  I got it.

Comment: I completed calculations. I think you have to integrate by parts three times. But anyway get your estimation. Thanks again.

Comment: No, twice is enough. See Edit.

Comment: Ah ok I did not manage your estimation and integrated a third time. So this was indeed not necessary. Thank you very much for your effort!